# What is the purpose of DataItem in the MVVM light sample code? Why is it implemented like this?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

I was given this sample code when creating a new MVVM light(WPF451) project and it made me confusing.

**DataItem.cs:**

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public DataItem(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

This class declares a set of properties that is needed in the ViewModel. It's used in the Model layer DataService, which provides data to the VM in its constructor.

**DataService.cs**

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public void GetData(Action<DataItem, Exception> callback)
    {
        // Use this to connect to the actual data service

        var item = new DataItem("Welcome to MVVM Light");
        callback(item, null);
    }
}
```

I thought it would be used in the VM as well to hold properties, like this:

```
public DataItem Data { get; set; }
```

but instead, the MVVM light developer decided to re-declare the properties in the VM.

**MainViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;

    private string _welcomeTitle = string.Empty;
    public string WelcomeTitle
    {
        get{ return _welcomeTitle; }
        set{ Set(ref _welcomeTitle, value); }
    }

    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _dataService.GetData(
            (item, error) =>
            {
                WelcomeTitle = item.Title;
            });
    }
}
```

I couldn't understand why they implemented like this. Yes, it reduces redundant INotifyPropertyChanged implemented object so it uses less resource. However, if I had to implement tons of properties to the VM, I'll have to write properties on both VM and DataItem, and also when I want to add or delete properties I'll have to edit both of them.

Couldn't I just hold a DataItem property in the VM? Or am I missing something?

Comment: "Couldn't I just hold a DataItem property in the VM?" Sure you could, but the model properties here don't raise a PropertyChanged event, because DataItem doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged. So you would still need a wrapper for each propery. However, if on update the DataItem instance is replaced by a new one, that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: There's about twenty "My view model HERP needs value A from property X from view model DERP.  How do I get it?" questions a week in the MVVM tag.  The simple answer is that HERP must reference DERP.  But people often can't figure out how to wire them together.  So some frameworks provide a generic means of communication between view models.  This is an example of a generic means of communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataItem` simply represents the `Model` in this case. If the `Model` is an entity that cannot be modified (database auto-generated POCO), this scenario would work.

Yes, you will have to have each applicable `Model` property in your `ViewModel` so that it can RaisePropertyChanged, and yes, this is more 'work', but it provides an abstraction between the two.

Some people are okay with modifying the `Model` to have it implement `INotiftyPropertyChanged`, others believe the `Model` shouldn't and all the work should be done in the `ViewModel` (which is what is being done in this case).

Comment: Thanks I finally got the light! Realised that the idea of Model was mixed up in my mind.